# laravel- datepicker is not showing?

Tags: laravel, datepicker

I want to implement a date picker in one of my text input page. I have a page call `panel.blade.php` and `app.blade.php` which is the layout page. Since Laravel comes with bootstrap and jquery installed, I did the usual import to include the necessary files to make it work.Below is the code.

app.blade.php:

```
<head>




<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
</style>



<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>

.
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
$('.date').datepicker({

  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'

});
    </script>
```

panel.blade.php:

```
 <tr>

        <td>454542</td>
        <td><input class="date form-control" type="text"></td>
        <td>Chair</td>
        <td>Received</td>
        <td>xxxx</td>                 

      </tr>
```

The problem is when I click on the textbox, it's supposed to pop out the date picker UI but nothing came out. I spent some time trying to figure out what went wrong but to no avail. Anyone can point out what went wrong?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming that Laravel includes Bootstrap and jquery, but I don't see it in a fresh install. (Are you using a template maybe?)

Put this lines in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And it should works perfectly ;)

**EDIT:**
Try putting the jquery import before the bootstrap datepicker import:

app.blade.php

```
<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
</style>



<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>
```

**EDIT2:**

To change the format you can also try to add a property to the input field:

```
<input class="date form-control" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Hope it works flawlessly!

Comment: yes i am using a template. But laravel did include BS and Jquery which is why I am able to get the layout for normal use. Why you say otherwise?

Comment: BTW,it doesn't work, it says panel:161 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function.

Comment: Did you put the jquery import before or after the bootstrap datepicker import? I have just installed a fresh laravel and I don't see the bootstrap neither jquery packages anywhere, try putting the jquery import BEFORE the bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: in the `app.blade.php`

Comment: Nope, not working. I got it to worked by putting the imports line of code in the `panel.blade.php`. Not sure why is that?

Comment: I tried changing the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` but it's not changing , it's still dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: I tried changing date format inside the datepicker function as shown by documentation but it's not working. why man.

Comment: Can you put all the code of your app.blade.php and panel.blade.php? And let me check in depth, must be something else wrong :/